# Stripe Cashier: Call to a member function subscribed() on null

Tags: laravel-4, stripe-payments

I am building a Stripe subscription PHP website using Laravel I am getting this error when I am trying to check if user is subscribed.

The error is in the view Laravel says its on this line  `@if ($user->subscribed())`.

My code:

```
@extends('temp.main')

@section('content')
    @if ($user->subscribed())
        <p>Subscribed</p>   
    @else
        <p>Not Subscribed </p>
    @endif
@stop
```

The error:

> Call to a member function subscribed() on null

```
<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>
<?php if($user->subscribed()): ?>
    <p>Subscribed</p>   
<?php else: ?>
    <p>Not Subscribed </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>

<?php echo $__env->make('temp.main', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

Comment: this just means that your `$user` is null here, where is that variable coming from?

Comment: protected $user;
 public function _construct()
 {
  $this->user=Auth::user();
 }
 public function getSubscription.(){

  return View::make('Subscriptionfolder.Subscription')->with('user',$this->user);
 }

Answer (score 1):

You need to check Auth::check() before using Auth::user()

Something like this:

```
@if (Auth::check() && !$user->subscribed())
```